# In LC-3 assembly language, how do I convert these commands to machine code?

Tags: assembly, lc3

For one of my classes I need to write an LC-3 program in machine code and I can't seem to find the machine codes for the commands that have a period for them:

```
.ORIG
.END
.BLKW
```

etc

Does anyone know what they are? I have all of the commands done, for example:
`AND R2, R2, #0` --> `0101 010 010 1 00000`

However I can't find what the first four bits for the `.ORIG`, `.END`, `.BLKW` commands are anywhere online.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with your particular dialect, but in most assembly languages, keywords starting with a `.` aren't instruction mnemonics but assembler directives.  In your case, it looks like possibly `.ORIG` means the start of a program and `.END` the end.  `.BLKW` seems like a memory filling operation of some kind.

Edit: I did a google search and came up with [this presentation](http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmpe012/Summer08/notes/07_LC3_Assembly_markup.pdf).  It says that `.ORIG` describes where to place the following block in memory.  For example `.ORIG 0x3000` would set the next instruction at address `0x3000`.  `.END`, as I mentioned above, describes the end of the program.  `.BLKW` means "block word" and is used to reserve space for use as an array, for example.

In all cases, there aren't any specific machine codes for these directives.  For `.ORIG`, just write out the following opcodes or data at the specified location.  `.END` won't show up in the machine code at all, and `.BLKW` means you can just copy the specified bytes directly from the assembly program into machine code.

Comment: That is what they mean, yes. In other assembly languages do those things not have a machine code interpretation?

Comment: @user1017593, no, they don't.  They're not instructions or data, so why would they?  They're just indications to the assembler about what to do with the contents of the program.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm new to all of this so it was confusing me.

Comment: When I try to convert it now it gives me errors for all of those codes. Line 10: Unexpected character '.' for .ORIG x3000

Comment: What do you mean "when I try to convert it"?  Aren't you doing that by hand?

Comment: Can you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708532/why-isnt-my-assembly-program-setting-r1-to-the-correct-value